# Disable Specific Page in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my app, I have Three "Tabs" that manages the view pager.

On top of the second view pager. I have a button that prevents the second "tab" from being selected, because I only have 2 Fragments that I want to show user.

Picture Instagram, the middle button is the camera button, but the left and the right tabs are for displaying fragments. I would like to achieve the same.

```
public class TabBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_bar);

        FragmentStatePagerItemAdapter fragmentStatePagerItemAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerItemAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
       .add(R.string.TABBAR_1_TITLE, ProfileFragment.class)
       .add(R.string.TABBAR_2_TITLE, BlankFragment.class)// I would like to disable this page  
       .add(R.string.TABBAR_3_TITLE, StatisticFragment.class)
                        .create());

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentStatePagerItemAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);


        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerTab);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    }
```

ANy ideas please?

I would like to have a Button on top of the second Tab, that is why I want to disable the second page.

P.S.: I am using this library https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: if you would like our help, please add code, screenshot and any more what may help us to understand your problem

Comment: @piotrek1543 I have edited the post. sorry.  I would like to have the viewPager disable that second page, because the second page is not needed